# conditioning for select the date in fullcallendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have a problem to create if else. So, I want if the date is only selected/clicked on one date (eg the 1st), the start and end date that appear in the modal are the same as the selected date.

if i set like this, it works fine.

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                $("#addEvent").modal("show");
                $("#addEvent .modal-title").text("Add Event");
                $("#addEvent #title").val("");
                $("#addEvent form").attr("action", "add");
                $("#addEvent form").removeAttr("data-id");
                $("#start_date").val(moment(start).format());
                $("#end_date").val(moment(start).format());
                $("#addEvent #start_clock").val("");
                $("#addEvent #end_clock").val("");
                $("#deleteEvent").html("");
            },
```

but the problem is that if i select a date, for example from the 1st to the 3rd, the start and end date are still the same 1. it should start at 1 end 3. so how do you make the conditioning? (I use fullcalendar js for the calendar). thank you for helping.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the scenario, but I can't reproduce the problem you're describing . Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/LYyXvvV?editable=true&editors=001 - if you select 1st-3rd of August, the dates reported in the console are what you'd expect (bearing in mind that end dates are exclusive in fullCalendar). (BTW `start` and `end` are already moment objects, you don't need to wrap them in moment() again). So perhaps you meant something else...can you clarify the issue?

Comment: thank you for notice my question. i will explain it once again. basically, the demo that you've made is as same as mine.  
that's basic right? but if you notice it, when you click just one date (example: 1st of August) the consoled reported that the start date is 1st and the end date is 2nd. 
the result of end date always plus one. what i want is not like that. if i select 1st of August, i want the start and the end date is still 1st. also if i select 1st - 4th of August, i want the start date is 1st and the end date is 4th. so how to make it possible?

Comment: `the result of end date always plus one`...that's because end dates in fullCalendar are **exclusive**, as explained in the documentation. If that doesn't suit what you need for your modal, just subtract one day from it before displaying - that's trivial using momentJS

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. but would you tell me how to subtract that end date? or the keyword related to it. i really have no idea to search it.

Comment: like I said, it's easy to do that with momentJS...have you consulted the momentJS documentation? You can find it in a short time.

Comment: alright, thank you so much. i'll check it.